# Add city to postal address when adding contact - Android

Tags: android, android-contacts

I am adding a contact through an Intent and am unable to figure out how to add the City to the Postal Address.  Using ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.POSTAL as the key, allows me to put the address in:

```
intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.POSTAL ,cm.getAddress());
```

but I'm not sure how to add the city.  In the API I see:

```
ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CITY
```

but I'm not sure how to use this.

Thanks for any ideas on this. I searched the Demos, but couldn't find anything.

Regards,
Julius.

Answer (score 2):

I am updating a contact's postal address through ContentResolver. If it helps here is my working code:

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
       cv.put(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, contactId);
       cv.put(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
        cv.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.STREET, streetAddress);
        cv.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CITY, city);
        cv.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.REGION, province);
        cv.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.POSTCODE, postalCode);
        cv.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.COUNTRY, country);
        int addressType = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE_HOME;
        cv.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE, addressType);

        try {
            getContentResolver().insert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, cv);
        } catch(Exception e)    {
            Log.i(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
```